# Correctly formatting GCM notifications?

Tags: android, push-notification, toast, google-cloud-messaging

I'm currently trying out the google cloud messaging service with its sample application "Guestbook." https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/

I'm attempting to send notifications that should appear as a simple "hello" toast on screen for about 5 seconds.Doing this from the project settings page (pictured here)works.Perhaps i've misinterpreted what this for.
[image: settings screen, allows me to broadcast a message to all]

However my attempts to do it manually via fiddler2  cause the guestbook client application to crash instead of making the intended toast flash up onscreen.

Here is an example of the POST request i used to attempt a push notification
[image: my attempts to push a notification to my registered device]

I have also done other variations of the above where i have included "topicId:_broadcast" to no avail.

Is there something in the formatting that i have wrong? or missing information i should have included.

Answer (score 1):

You got the format a bit wrong. It should be :

```
{
  "registration_ids":["xxx", "yyy"],
  "data": {
    "message": "test",
    "duration": "5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Still crashes the application unfortunately.

Comment: @ChristopherLawless In that case, you should post the application code that crashes and the LogCat of the crash.

Comment: it's the android guestbook sample client for cloud messaging here https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/repository/mbs/android

Comment: @ChristopherLawless I'm not going to download that code in order to find your problem. Please post the relevant code in your question.